# Is it possible to escape maven property interpolation when the property value string is the same as the property name?

Tags: maven

I am trying to define a maven property:

```
<properties>
  <property>$${property}</property>
</property>
```

Maven tries to expand ${property} and I get the following error:

```
[ERROR]     Resolving expression: '${property}': Detected the
     following recursive expression cycle in 'property': [property] -> [Help 2]
```

I have tried all sorts of combinations to try to escape it, without success:

```
$$
\$
\$$
```

etc etc

Note: the interpolation is escaped when the property value is not the same as the name.

Is this possible?

Comment: What's the context for this? As you've found, several obvious approaches don't work, so it would be helpful to know the constraints when trying to construct a workaround.

Comment: It's a little bit involved. I am assembling a doc package built from a multi-module maven project, using docbook as the source format. This property is in a auto-generated footer. For most modules, the value of this property is substituted using a docbook property, but I have a common module for which I want to delay substitution of the property, hence wanting to set it to ${property}. I do have a (completely different) workaround, but I would still like to know whether this is possible in maven (as advertised, and as works when the property name is not the same as the value).

Answer (score 1):

Since it seems you can't build a maven property (even with intermediate properties), maybe you can keep 2 separate properties and concatenate them where you need. Let's say you want to populate some property in a file.

Define the 2 variables in the POM:

```
<properties>
    <property>{property}</property>
    <dollar>$</dollar>
</properties>
```

use both when defining the property in the file:

```
# variable from file which is to be filtered
whatever=${dollar}${property}
```

and upon filtering you'll end up with:

```
# variable from file which is to be filtered
whatever=${property}
```

---

<strike>What about using `&amp;`? A configuration such as:</strike>

```
  <properties>
      <property>&amp;{property}</property>
  </properties>

  ...

  <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>echo-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>echo</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <echos>
                    <echo>property=[${property}]</echo>
                </echos>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
  </plugins>
```

will output:

```
[INFO] --- echo-maven-plugin:0.2:echo (default) @ XXXX ---
[INFO] property=[&{property}]
```

Comment: I don't want & - I want $.

Comment: Apologies, although I kept reading `$` I was absolutely convinced you needed `&` (facepalm)

Comment: @natk Right, all I tried so far in defining the property failed because it finds the cyclic reference. Depending on how you need to use the property, maybe you can use the updated answer as a workaround.

Comment: Yes, that would work if I could change where I instantiate the property, but since I am using it in multiple locations, some of which another value does get substituted in, I cannot use your solution. Thanks though!

Answer (score -1):

`&#36;{property}` should work fine.

Comment: LOL. That should have been &#36;{property}, but the browser converted to $ for me automatically.