# Maven replacer: replacement value containing dollar signs

Tags: maven, maven-replacer-plugin

I am dealing with a Maven script where I have to modify some file content. I am currently using the replacer plugin, which gives me trouble when the replacement value contains dollar signs.

The replacement I have problems with is relatively simple: in my log4j.xml, replace the line `<param name="File" value="wat.log" />`with `<param name="File" value="${FOO_BAR}/wat.log" />`

I know that, written like that, Maven would interpret `${FOO_BAR}` as property. I looked up a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23987112/is-it-possible-to-escape-maven-property-interpolation-when-the-property-value-st) and tried it. When I just use `${FOO}`

```xml
<properties>
    <dollar>$</dollar>
    <foo>{FOO_BAR}</foo>
    <dollar.foo>${dollar}${foo}</dollar.foo>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.google.code.maven-replacer-plugin</groupId>
            <artifactId>replacer</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>configure-logging</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>replace</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>${my.configDir}/log4j.xml</include>
                        </includes>
                        <replacements>
                            <replacement>
                                <token>value="wat.log"</token>
                                <value>value="${dollar.foo}/wat.log"</value>
                            </replacement>
                        </replacements>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

The result is an error `named capturing group is missing trailing '}'`. As I understand it, the plugin uses the usual Java regex replacement which interprets dollar signs and curlies in the replacement text for capturing groups in the regex.

I tried a few other things, and it seems the specific error in this case is due to the underscore. If I change the `foo` property to `{FOOBAR}`, the error changes: `No group with name {FOOBAR}`.

I tried a few other things as well:

- changing the `foo` property to `{foo}`, I don't get an error, but the replacement drops the `$`, i.e. I get `value="{foo}/wat.log"` - a second replacement of `foo` with `FOO_BAR` works, but I still am missing the dollar sign
- changing the property to `{dollar}` gives me an `Illegal group reference` error
- escaping the dollar, braces and/or underscores in several different ways (e.g. `$$`, `\$`, `\\$`) did not bring me any further, neither did using unicode or $ for the dollar sign.

Is there a way to actually solve this with Maven? I'd be happy to use more properties, more replacements or an entirely different plugin.

**Update:** I am working on Windows - not sure if/how that affects the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer myself, looking for another problem related to backslashes:
Add `<regex>false</regex>` to the configuration of the replacer plugin, then the replacer will just replace the plain text it sees and the `${dollar.foo}` trick works as intended:

```xml
<properties>
    <dollar>$</dollar>
    <foo>{FOO_BAR}</foo>
    <dollar.foo>${dollar}${foo}</dollar.foo>
</properties>

...
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>
                            <include>${my.configDir}/log4j.xml</include>
                        </includes>


                        <!-- don't treat token/value as regular expressions -->
                        <regex>false</regex>


                        <replacements>
                            <replacement>
                                <token>value="wat.log"</token>
                                <value>value="${dollar.foo}/wat.log"</value>
                            </replacement>
                        </replacements>
                    </configuration>
...
```

Comment: Ok, I am glad to see your problem got resolved. The strange thing is that according to the documentation, that parameter controls if the _token_ contains any regex characters.

Comment: Yes, but it seems that the possible presence of regexes in the token also triggers the evaluation of regex capturing groups in the value which was source of the problem. So the docs are a bit unclear about that.

Answer (score 9):

You are very close. Just prepend the `$` character with an escaping back-slash:

```
...
<replacements>
  <replacement>
    <token>value="wat.log"</token>
    <value>value="\${dollar.foo}/wat.log"</value>
  </replacement>
</replacements>
...
```

log4j.xml, before:

```
<param name="File" value="wat.log" />
```

log4j.xml, after:

```
<param name="File" value="${FOO_BAR}/wat.log" />
```

It worked for me.

Comment: Well, it did not work for me - as I have written, I tried that way of escaping the dollar

Comment: Ok, maybe I am missing something here. I'll set up my project at Github when I get home for you to take a look at. I'll get back to you.

Comment: For what it's worth, my example is available at https://github.com/dr01g/maven-replace-example.git

Comment: @ArneMertz That's weird indeed, because I tested Daniel solution and it worked fine for me also (I'm the one who upvoted this). Maybe a different Maven version then?

Comment: Strange indeed. I have tried it successfully on Maven 3.3.1 on Mac OS X 10.11/JDK8 and Maven 3.3.3 on Windows 7 Enterprise/JDK8.